# Overloading constructor with a generic type in java

Tags: java, constructor, overloading

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by IDEA on 15/11/14.
 */
public class Matrix<T> {
    private final int nrow;
    private final int ncol;

    Matrix(List<List<T>> data) {
        nrow = data.size();
        ncol = data.get(0).size();
    }

    Matrix(List<T[]> data) {
        nrow = data.size();
        ncol = data.get(0).length;
    }
}
```

The IDE asks me to delete the first constructor, why?

Comment: How can you "rename" a constructor?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> The IDE asks me to rename or delete the first constructor, why?

It's because of the way generics work in Java. Due to *type erasure*, you're effectively declaring two constructors like this:

```
Matrix(List data)
```

That's what the JVM sees, with some added metadata about the type arguments involved.

This isn't just for constructors - you can't overload methods based on generic type arguments, either.

See the [Java Generics FAQ entry on type erasure](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ101) for the gruesome details.

It's odd that your constructor only needs the row and column count, but here's a version using static factory methods:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Matrix<T> {
    private final int nrow;
    private final int ncol;

    private Matrix(int nrow, int ncol) {
        this.nrow = nrow;
        this.ncol = ncol;
    }

    public static <T> Matrix<T> fromArrays(List<T[]> data) {
        return new Matrix<T>(data.size(), data.get(0).length);
    }

    public static <T> Matrix<T> fromLists(List<? extends List<T>> data) {
        return new Matrix<T>(data.size(), data.get(0).size());
    }
}
```

And a demo of using this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // We're only checking the compilation for the moment :)
        List<List<String>> lists = null;
        List<String[]> arrays = null;

        Matrix<String> x = Matrix.fromArrays(arrays);
        Matrix<String> y = Matrix.fromLists(lists);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you suggest in a situation like this? Overloading based on a generic type is needed but not available.

Comment: @qed: You could have two static factory methods with different names which both call to the same constructor.

Comment: In that case I may skip the constructor all together?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the static factory method approach a bit in your answer? Thanks!

Comment: @qed: Well which bit don't you understand? You have two static methods, each of them returning a `Matrix`, but with different names so they're not overloads. They both call the same constructor.

Comment: If both methods call Matrix(), wouldn't we be back to where we started?

Comment: @qed: No, because you'd have *one* constructor - there'd be no overloading anywhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65016/discussion-between-qed-and-jon-skeet).

Comment: @qed: I don't have time to chat right now, but I've added a sample to my answer

Answer (score 4):

Because both the constructors have same signatures (same number of parameters and same type). The generic types are not enough to make overloaded constructors/methods and that is because of type erasure.

Both the constructors are treated as `Matrix(List a)` due to type erasure.